# Using external Web IDE in Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating an app for my company.

The thing is, I work on a governmental company and have several restrictions. I can use the google services including apps scripts and cloud services (the free services only) but ideally I can't install any IDE locally so I a web IDE would be the ideal solution.
But I am having a hard time to understand how can I export/import my scripts, I mean, I can't even find them on drive (I can find my project and that's it).

Some web based IDE's can be authorized, and some other will be blocked, this one: https://shiftedit.net/ seems to work.

I am just not understanding it?

Comment: You can use the Drive API to find script project files.  I've always been happy using googles script editors and you can save your script files as ascii text files with Apps Script API which makes it easier to backup your files without creating unnecessary projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script project files (.gs and .html) are not files that can be found in the Google Drive user interface. To export / download these files you could use [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api), [CLASP](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp), [Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-apps-script-github/lfjcgcmkmjjlieihflfhjopckgpelofo?hl=en).

P.S. I just found https://github.com/dev-container/gas but have not tried yet... it' for working on Google Apps Script projects with VS Code and GitPod containers.

Related

- [How best to develop Google Sheets scripts and Git versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47894679/1595451)
- [Is it possible to upload a .gs file to an apps script project of a copied google doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68894304/1595451)

Comment: The thing with CLASP it's that it's seems I need to install something on my machine. But I can't install anything without authorization and should avoid it